# Stuck with this php error: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float

Tags: php, wordpress

Our website was poorly designed about 10 years ago and my PHP is so rusty. We are attempting to update our PHP version from 5.6 (I know!) and errors are flying up left and right.

The error: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be float, string given in
...

This is the string with the error:

```
$comps .= '<input type="checkbox" name="addons[]" class="addons" data-name="'.$component->name.'" data-price="'.$component->unit_price.'" value="'.$component->id.'" /> Add for $'.  number_format($component->unit_price,2);
```

The value is coming from a series of not-required checkboxes to choose a priced add-on. I believe that the issue is coming up because the value is not a number and that's what it expects. Any thoughts on how I can amend this string to fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [floatval](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php) function to convert from string to float in order to avoid these errors:

```
number_format(floatval($component->unit_price), 2);
```

Comment: I had a feeling it would be something easy to fix. That did the trick. Thanks so much for your help!